# Perl: Error printing after do-while loop

Tags: perl

I am making a concatenating do-while loop wherein each of the entered strings will be added to the main string `$food`. Here is the code:

```
do {
  print("\nEnter your order(-1 to end): ");
  $order = <>;
  chop($order);

  if ($order != -1) {
   $food .= " ".$order;
   print($food);
  }  
} while ( $order != -1)

print ($food); #PROBLEM HERE!
```

The problem is that whenever I put `print ($food)` **outside the loop**, a syntax error for this line appears plus an `Execution of file.pl aborted due to compilation errors` message.

The code works once I put `print ($food)` inside the loop but I am curious to why this error is happening.

Comment: `Execution of file.pl aborted due to compilation errors` is not the error message. You completely ignored the actual error message, `syntax error at script.pl line 12, near ") print"`.

Comment: Use `chomp` not `chop` its safer version.

Comment: I dislike `do while` in general. It's not even useful here since you check the condition twice per iteration! What I'd use: `while (1) { print(...); $order = <>; last if !defined($order); chomp($order); last if $order eq -1; $food .= " $order"; } print "$food\n";`

Comment: @ikegami: I really appreciate your comment! I'm actually just starting with Perl and all its semantics hence the crude code but thanks for the correction. Plus your suggestion has new stuff to learn! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line before last print has syntax error - it does not end with `;`.
Just add it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A thing worth mentioning in addition to the syntax error: I see that you you start the string with a newline. While this is fine, it might be considered "better" to end strings with the newline before printing, as printing a newline would result in flushing the STDOUT buffer right away. In most cases, this is the behavior you want, as it prevents delayed output and text flickering (especially if printing a lot).

Comment: Thank you for the correction! 
I always welcome hacks for the best practices in programming.

Comment: @thekalaban Personally i've made the habit out of always ending the string with a newline, unless more will be appended to it. I wouldn't go as far as call it a "best practice", but it results in the desired behavior more often than not :)   On a related note, you might want to check out the autoflush setting determined by `$|`

Comment: Noted, sir!
Okay, I'll check that out too!